# What does org.apache.myfaces.MARK_INITIAL_STATE_WHEN_APPLY_BUILD_VIEW do?

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, myfaces

I found in MyFaces 2.2 documentation the following context parameter:

[org.apache.myfaces.MARK_INITIAL_STATE_WHEN_APPLY_BUILD_VIEW](https://myfaces.apache.org/core22/myfaces-impl/webconfig.html#org_apache_myfaces_MARK_INITIAL_STATE_WHEN_APPLY_BUILD_VIEW)

But the documentation does not state what is its purpose:

> Description: 
>   no description

What does it do in a JSF 2.2 application?

Answer (score 0):

`org.apache.myfaces.MARK_INITIAL_STATE_WHEN_APPLY_BUILD_VIEW`is a `web config param` in MyFaces.

It allows you to call markInitialState() only after the view is built

Comment: Thank you. Does it mean it changes the way/timing the MyFaces runtime handles the initial state marking, or is it only useful if we handle this ourselves? Did you already use this parameter in a real-world example to see what kind of problems it can solve?

Comment: I did not use that parameter yet, someone  have to find a good example. sorry